# Index utilization issues in SQL Server queries

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, index-tuning, query-performance

These days I have to optimize queries written by someone long back and I don't have business info behind them.So trying to optimize them a safe way,without hampering business logic.
While tuning queries, I have come across some doubts which I want to be clear.

The table source_price_curve is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[source_price_curve](
    [source_curve_def_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [as_of_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Assessment_curve_type_value_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [curve_source_value_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [maturity_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [curve_value] [float] NOT NULL,
    [create_user] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [create_ts] [datetime] NULL,
    [update_user] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [update_ts] [datetime] NULL,
    [bid_value] [float] NULL,
    [ask_value] [float] NULL,
    [is_dst] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [IX_unique_source_curve_def_id_index] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [as_of_date] ASC,
    [source_curve_def_id] ASC,
    [maturity_date] ASC,
    [is_dst] ASC,
    [curve_source_value_id] ASC,
    [Assessment_curve_type_value_id] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[source_price_curve]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_source_curve_def_id] FOREIGN KEY([source_curve_def_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[source_price_curve_def] ([source_curve_def_id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[source_price_curve] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_source_curve_def_id]
GO
```

It has around 130 million records.The following indexes are defined within this table.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [source_curve_def_id_index] ON [dbo].[source_price_curve]
(
    [as_of_date] ASC,
    [source_curve_def_id] ASC,
    [maturity_date] ASC,
    [is_dst] ASC,
    [curve_source_value_id] ASC
)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [source_price_curve_123] ON [dbo].[source_price_curve]
(
    [source_curve_def_id] ASC,
    [as_of_date] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [maturity_date]) 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PT_source_price_curve_as_of_date_curve_source_value_id] 
ON [dbo].[source_price_curve]
(
    [as_of_date] ASC,
    [curve_source_value_id] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [curve_value],
    [maturity_date],
    [source_curve_def_id])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PT_source_price_curve_as_of_date_curve_source_value_id_Assessment_curve_type_value_id] 
ON [dbo].[source_price_curve]
(
    [as_of_date] ASC,
    [curve_source_value_id] ASC,
    [Assessment_curve_type_value_id] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [curve_value],
    [maturity_date],
    [source_curve_def_id]) 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PT_source_price_curve_maturity_date] ON [dbo].[source_price_curve]
(
    [maturity_date] ASC
)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PT_source_price_curve_source_curve_def_id_curve_source_value_id]
 ON [dbo].[source_price_curve]
(
    [source_curve_def_id] ASC,
    [curve_source_value_id] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [as_of_date],
    [Assessment_curve_type_value_id],
    [curve_value],
    [is_dst],
    [maturity_date]) 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PT_source_price_curve_source_curve_def_id111] 
ON [dbo].[source_price_curve]
(
    [source_curve_def_id] ASC,
    [Assessment_curve_type_value_id] ASC,
    [curve_source_value_id] ASC,
    [maturity_date] ASC,
    [as_of_date] ASC
)
```

I run a query as follows:

```
SELECT @tenor_from =CONVERT(DATETIME,MIN(spc.maturity_date),103)  
FROM source_price_curve spc  
WHERE spc.as_of_date >= @as_of_date_from
```

The execution plan of this query is provided in the below link:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ2_3boSZ

I wonder why it is utilizing index IX_PT_source_price_curve_maturity_date(with index on maturity date column only) when filter condition is on as_of_date(while selecting data from source_price_curve).
Why isn't it utilizing the clustered index which has as_of_date as the first column in index order ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is looking for the minimum `maturity_date` from rows where the `as_of_date` is greater than a given value.

The optimizer has to choose between two main execution strategies:

1. Scan an index **ordered** by `maturity_date ASC` until it finds **the first row** where `as_of_date >= @as_of_date_from`.

   As soon as the query processor finds this first row, the scan of the index stops. This is a point often missed when reading execution plans: an index scan does not necessarily always scan the whole index.

   If the first qualifying row can be found quickly, a *partial* scan of the ordered index is a great strategy for your query. On the other hand, this is a poor strategy if the first row matching the `as_of_date` predicate occurs toward the end of the index (in `maturity_date` order).

   The optimizer therefore makes an assessment of how many rows from the index it will have to scan before it finds one that matches the `as_of_date` predicate. This assessment is based on an assumption of uniform distribution (often incorrect in practice).

   The plan you provided shows that the Index Scan had to read 1,101,479 rows (in maturity date order) before it found the first one matching the `as_of_date` predicate.
2. **Seek** an index (with `as_of_date` as the leading key) to find **all** rows where `as_of_date >= @as_of_date_from`, then compute the **minimum** `maturity_date` found in those rows.

   This is a good strategy if the `as_of_date` predicate matches relatively few rows. It is not so good if many rows are expected to qualify. The expected cost of this strategy depends on the value of `@as_of_date_from`, and statistical information about the `as_of_date` column.

   Your query uses a local variable, so the optimizer cannot 'see' the value contained in it, and makes a **guess** at how selective the unknown value will be.

   For an inequality predicate, the default guess is that 30% of the rows will qualify. For a table of 130 million rows, the optimizer will therefore guess that 30% * 130,000,000 = 39,000,000 rows will match. This is a lot of rows to compute the minimum `maturity_date` on, the the optimizer prefers the other strategy.

   You can allow the optimizer to 'see' the value inside the variable at execution time by adding an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint to the query. This enables the [Parameter Embedding Optimization](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options), at the cost of having to recompile the query plan every time the query is executed.

   If the `@as_of_date_from` variable value varies a lot between executions, using the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint may be worthwhile for you. The optimizer may still choose the partial ordered scan strategy, depending on its assessment of the relative costs of the two strategies.

---

In any case, you should change the data type of the `@as_of_date_from` to `datetime` to match the `as_of_date` column to avoid an implicit conversion.

The data type of `@tenor_from` should probably be `datetime` not `varchar(20)`. Or change the query to `CONVERT(varchar(20),MIN(spc.maturity_date),103)`. The current `CONVERT` makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder why it is utilizing index
>   IX_PT_source_price_curve_maturity_date(with index on maturity date
>   column only) when filter condition is on as_of_date(while selecting
>   data from source_price_curve). Why isnt it utilizing the clustered
>   index which has as_of_date as the first column in index order ?

The `IX_PT_source_price_curve_maturity_date` is the **narrowest** index containing all the query needs (it needs `maturity_date` and `as_of_date` only) that's why it's chosen.

Every non-clustered index over the clustered table has row locators = clustered index keys, so this index and every other non-clustered index has a wide horrible clustered index key:

```
as_of_date, source_curve_def_id, maturity_date, is_dst, curve_source_value_id + uniquefier
```

at least in the leaf level, but when the non-clustered index is not unique, not only in its leaf level, but even in every intermediate level too.

Your query has to do the scan anyway because it has a predicate >= unknown (`@as_of_date_from` that is a variable and is not sniffed), so there is no gain to use an index that has `as_of_date` as a leading column (server estimates that 30% of rows will meet the criteria `spc.as_of_date >= @as_of_date_from`), because it's a clustered index and so it contains all the data, it's the "heaviest" thing to read and here the server just chooses the most "lightweigth" index to load it from disk.

The other non-clustered index definitions show that he has created them has no idea about clustered index key already included in all the non clustered index, because all of them contain a part of clustered index key in the included columns

Answer (score 2):

Actually, an index scan of the `IX_PT_source_price_curve_maturity_date` is almost certainly the fastest possible way to get the value desired.

We're looking at the whole table, and need the minimum `maturity_date` where the `as_of` date meets the criteria. How is the index sorted? By `maturity_date`, lowest to highest. So, it goes through the rows in order, and the first row that meets the `as_of` date requirement is the row it needs.

As has been noted in previous iterations of this question, the query with the temp table is slower because what it's doing is fundamentally different. It has to make sure that it's only looking at rows in `source_price_curve` that match a row in the temp table, and it has to do that first.

If there would only ever be one ID to check, then you could pass that in as a variable, and it would probably go back to the index scan, checking for the first row where the ID matched, and the `as_of` date was in range.

Or, it might not - if the selectivity of the ID is good enough, it's going to decide that it makes the most sense to find all the rows with that ID, instead of searching rows in `maturity_date` order until it finds one with that ID and the right `as_of` date.

If one out of 100000 rows have that ID (1,300 rows), then it very well might be faster to find the right record by pulling the 1300 and just checking them.